# Matcher: "No match found..."

Tags: java, regex

I'm getting an error in matcher saying "No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:468)".

My commented code's below.  I've been changing the number within m.group, so I now suspect something's up with my regex.  Archetype's a string like this: We #plan_to# #deliver# #highly_effective# #esolutions# for today's #data_driven# #market_leaders#.

```
List<String> phraseCollection = parserHelper.getPhrases(fileKontent,"phrases:");
    String archetype = parserHelper.getRandomElement(phraseCollection);
    boolean flagga = true;
    while(flagga == true){
    Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("#[^#]+#");
    Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(archetype);
    String fromMatcher = m.group(0);//first word surrounded by hash, without the hash
    String col = ":";
    String token = fromMatcher+col;//token to pass to getPhrase
    List<String> pCol = parserHelper.getPhrases(fileKontent, token);
    String repl = parserHelper.getRandomElement(pCol); //new word to replace with
    String hash = "#";
    String tk2 = hash + fromMatcher + hash;  //word surrounded by hash to be replaced, hash and all
    archetype = parserHelper.replace(archetype, tk2, repl);  //now archetype should have 1 less hashed word
    flagga = m.find();  //false when all hash gone
    }
    String theArcha = archetype;

    return theArcha;
```

Comment: `flagga == true` are you really sure it is true? You better write `(flagga==true)==true && (flagga!=false) != false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you never call find before trying to get group, that is why you don't have match.

You need this line of code:

```
m.find();
```

Before you do

```
String fromMatcher = m.group(0); //first word surrounded by hash, without the hash
```

But even then, you will get it all with hash tags around, to avoid that you should create group only for inner text around hash tags like this:

```
 Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("#([^#]+)#");
```

And when you are accessing your group it will be group number 1 (because 0 is whole pattern). So change getting group like this:

```
String fromMatcher = m.group(1); //first word surrounded by hash, without the hash
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  The code's running.  It has trouble sometimes handling the words with underscores such as "plan_to"  Does the regex you provided work the same way on those as it does on words only containing letters?

Comment: *I isolated and fixed the problem, which was within my parserHelper.getphrases() method.  Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad it worked :) Regex works, the same way, it just groups inner match to group 1.